# .whl is not supported wheel on this platform when pip installing GDAL on Windows 10-64 bit

Tags: python, gdal, geonode

I am working on Windows 10 64 bit. Installed GDAL 3.3.1-1 via OSGEO4W setup file which according to the tutorial available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZFV2tPgusXM), Gdal installation should be done via pip install GDAL‑3.3.1‑pp37‑pypy37_pp73‑win_amd64.whl.

I downloaded the .whl file from [Laboratory of Fluorescence Dynamics](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) however, I am getting the error message that the .whl file is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Initially, I thought Python 2.7 was causing the problem, cleaned start the installation on a new machine with no Python at all, started over with the Geonode configuration process and still getting the same error, also did upgrade pip.

Comment: Check 'pip install wheel' and see if it helps.

Comment: when 'pip install wheel', response-requirement already satisfied in the geonode_env

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cp39` stand for **Python version** installed on my PC. I am using the latest Python 3.9, so `GDAL-3.3.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` should be downloaded. And then the GDAL was successfully installed.